# "than been married" vs "than being married"

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

I am having problem with how to use been and being properly in essays. I came across following sentence and would like to learn through this example about the difference.

- It can be seen commonly in every part of the world that women tend to be alone than being married.
- It can be seen commonly in every part of the world that women tend to be alone than been married.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*than been married* is completely ungrammatical, but *than being married* is. Whenever *been* is used, the verb *to have* is involved one way or the other. To put it in simple terms, every time you want to use *been*, you must precede it with one of the forms of the verb *to have*. Here is the list of all possible combinations:

> have been
>   has been
>   having been
>   had been

That's why *than been married* is not correct. Does this make sense?

Comment: It order to check if I get your point correctly, If I write above sentence as follows, would it become grammatically correct? It can be seen commonly in every part of the world that women tend to be alone than have been married.

Comment: No. Typically, "than" can't be followed by a verb in its base form.